# Paste formula into next free column

Tags: vba, excel

Following issue: I want to update a report and its formulas based on a date cell (located in first row). Loop should go until yesterday's date. This is how the sheet looks like:

[image]

How do add the date dynamically is achieved, now I want to update the corresponding formulas below (row 2 - 35) up until the newest date entry. This is what code I have written so far:

```
Sub Update_Newest_Day_Conversions()

Worksheets("CPC - Conversions DoD").Range("A1"). _
End(xlToRight).Select

MyDate = Date - 1

While ActiveCell.Value < MyDate

ActiveCell.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveRange.Copy Offset(0, 1)

Wend

End Sub
```

The formula stops working when I try to copy the active selected range and I receive the following error message:

> Compile Error: sub or function not defined.

It points out to the `Offset(0,1)` method. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I know I'm pretty close.

Comment: You possibly want `Cells(ActiveCell).End(xlDown).Select`. But why are you selecting so many cells?

Comment: I'm not? xlDown only would go down to row 35, the last cell where a formula is located and is then supposed to copy this range into the next column

Comment: If the formulas 2:35 can be copied to the right having code for this job is a waste of time. Instead, enter a date in F1. In E1 enter `=F1+1`. Copy E1 to the right as far as you have formulas in rows 2:35. Now, to add a day select the entire last column, copy and paste in the adjacent column - faster than you can call the macro.

Comment: There is some other sheets which reference the newest date, where in turn I'd have to write more formulas for them not to take all the unused dates into account.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. I have amended it to accommodate the more precise description of your requirements.

```
Sub Update_Newest_Day_Conversions()
    ' 19 Feb 2018

    Dim MyDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim C As Long                               ' column counter

    MyDate = Date - 1
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With Worksheets("CPC - Conversions DoD")
        C = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row
        LastDate = .Cells(1, C).Value
        Do While LastDate < MyDate
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, C), .Cells(Rl, C))
            Rng.Copy Rng.Offset(0, 1)
            LastDate = LastDate + 1
            C = C + 1
            .Cells(1, C).Value = LastDate
            .Columns(C).AutoFit
        Loop
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately, this solution does not loop over the columns and basically just adds one column equal to yesterday's date, effectively neglecting all the other days. The report is not updated daily, so sometimes there may be three or four days missing. Thanks for your efforts so far though!

Comment: I thought the code provides for exactly what you describe. What needs to be done with the other dates?

Comment: for example, let's assume the last updated date is the 10th of February, so in this case I would not only need the 18th (yesterday's date), but all the other missing days in between (11th - 18th February). Hence why I used a loop..

Comment: I have expanded the code to fill in the days between the last date found and `MyDate`.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution in case anybody's interested:

```
Sub Update_Newest_Day_Conversions()

Worksheets("CPC - Conversions DoD").Range("A1"). _
End(xlToRight).Select


MyDate = Date - 1

While ActiveCell.Value < MyDate

ActiveCell.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select

Wend

End Sub
```